# how to use dot matrix printer in vb.net? also how to use form feed in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, printing

I am using **VB.Net 8** and I want to print through **Dot Matrix printer**. I have included the following code which is not working properly.

```
e.Graphics.DrawString("First Page", New Font("Draft", 10), Brushes.Black, New Point(100, 100))
e.Graphics.DrawString(vbFormFeed, New Font("Arial", 10), Brushes.Black, New Point(100, 100))
e.Graphics.DrawString("Second Page", New Font("Draft", 10), Brushes.Black, New Point(100, 150))
```

Comment: Maybe you can provide more information to help us understand your problem.  For example, the error message.

Comment: e.graphics is fine to print lines but i want to know , how to use form feed using e.graphics

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/322090/how-to-send-raw-data-to-a-printer-by-using-visual-basic-.net